# How do i replace ***** with 50 digit, * with 5, ** with 10 in out program?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Image of test.xslm table]

How do i replace ***** with 50 digit, * with 5, ** with 10?
The program work wrong and change all values to 50 only.
How do i change value according to number of *?

```
Sub FillTitle()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'Detect last data entry row in Column E.
    
    For Each rng In Range("E2:E" & lrow)
        If rng <> "*****" Then
            rng = "50"
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

How do i change value according to number of *?

Comment: I see in your example you have 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 stars.   What values do you want for three and four stars?

Comment: 3 and 4 stars also give 50.

Comment: Hi Vitaly, you can change your IF to be IF LEN(rng) = 0 THEN rng = "" ELSEIF len(rng) = 1 THEN rng = "5" ELSEIF len(rng) = 2 THEN rng = "10" ELSE rng = "50" END IF

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right track.

Instead:

```
For Each rng In Range("E2:E" & lrow)
    If rng.value = "*****" Then
        rng.value = "50"
    ElseIf rng.value = "**" Then 
        rng.value = "10"
    ElseIf rng.value = "*" Then 
        rng.value = "5"
    End If
Next rng
```

You could also consider a [Select/Case pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement), which is a little less verbose:

```
 For Each rng In Range("E2:E" & lrow)
    Select Case rng.Value
        Case "*****"
            rng.Value = 50
        Case "**"
            rng.Value = 10
        Case "*"
            rng.Value = 5
    End Select
Next rng
```

Or using a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to manage the translation:

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Set up dictionary
dict.Add "*****", 50
dict.Add "**", 10
dict.Add "*", 5

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'Detect last data entry row in Column E.

For Each rng In Range("E2:E" & lrow)
    If dict.Exists(rng.Value) Then rng.Value = dict(rng.Value)
Next rng
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling Excel built-in `Replace` method is more efficient to get it done.

- The asterisk is a wildcard character, so add a tilde (~) before asterisk to search it.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceStart()
    Dim arrKey, iKey
    Const SWHAT = "~*"
    ' Modify as needed, Array(5, 50) means: replace 5 stars with 50
    arrKey = Array(Array(5, 50), Array(2, 10), Array(1, 5))
    For Each iKey In arrKey
        Range("E:E").Replace WHAT:=Application.Rept(SWHAT, iKey(0)), _
            Replacement:=iKey(1), LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Find or replace text and numbers on a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)